# Finalizar o script PHP com "exit" deletaria todas as variáveis e destrói objetos?

Tags: php

Olá, no PHP usando as funções **unset($variavel)** eu deleto a **$variavel**, no **$Objeto->__destruct** eu destruo mas ainda sim uso **unset($Objeto)**.

Minha duvida é, caso eu use a função **exit** sem deletar ou destruir nada...

> a finalização do script deletaria tudo que foi iniciado ou não ?
>
> como isso faz diferença e qual importância de deletar tudo que foi
>   chamado ou vamos dizer criado (variáveis, array e objetos)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SIM.

Está no manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php
(pra variar, em português faltam pedaços importantes na tradução)

> **exit** — Output a message and terminate the current script
>   Description
>
> ```
>  void exit ([ string $status ] )
>  void exit ( int $status )
> ```
>
> Terminates execution of the script. **Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called**.

A parte grifada é mais ou menos isto:

> *Funções de encerramento e destrutores de objeto são sempre executados, mesmo se usado exit*

("Mesmo usado exit", pois isto ocorre ao final do *script*, de qualquer forma)

**Resumo:** usar `exit` ou seu sinônimo `die` dá na mesma que o script acabar "naturalmente". São liberados todos os recursos (o que é uma das razões para OOP em PHP ser um desperdício de recursos, cada requisição tem que recriar tudo quanto é classe de novo pra poder usar).

Outra coisa, `unset` não é coisa normal de se usar em PHP. Tem que ter uma razão muito boa pra isso, em situações muito específicas. Em condições normais o PHP, como a maior parte das linguagens de script, gerencia a memória para você.

Um exemplo de uso válido do `unset` é o mencionado pelo colega Jorge Matheus nos comentários, quando se aplica a uma variável da `$_SESSION`. Isto porque aí já não se trata mais de memória, e sim de dados que são gravados normalmente no disco, para que o próximo script recupere. Aí faz sentido limpar, pois é algo que o PHP vai gravar no encerramento, e se é algo não mais desejável, não tem razão de preservar a informação.

Ainda assim, vale a observação sobre OOP feita antes, pois um objeto persistido na *session* precisa ser lido do arquivo ou DB, e de-serializado para se transformar em objeto de novo.

Comment: Bacco, referente a citação do `unset`, o mesmo é adequado para "destruir" uma sessão, por exemplo?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus só depende da sua necessidade. Por uma questão de segurança, em vez de eu destruir uma sessão eu prefiro esvaziar ela com `$_SESSION = [];` ou mesmo `$_SESSION['objeto'] = null;` por exemplo,  assim evita reaproveitamento de cookie. Em outros casos você pode zerar um ID de usuário na session, reaproveitando a mesma no caso do usuário logar e deslogar. De qq forma, o UNSET nesse caso ainda faz algum sentido, pq você está usando para matar algo que foge do script (a session por padrão é gravada em disco). Já não faz sentido se for  'liberar memória' em variáveis comuns

Comment: @JorgeMatheus Resumindo, `unset` em session cai no que eu chamei de "razão boa" ou "situação específica" ;)

Comment: Show Bacco! Fiz a pergunta pois uso a função no `logout` dos usuários.

Comment: ótima resposta como sempre. Valeu!

Comment: Antes de perguntar havia buscado no [php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exit.php) mas realmente a descrição não confere com a da página em inglês que você enviou. Obrigado =D